# How can I stop an image being used on the "pictures" live tile

Tags: tiles, pictures

I always assumed that the images used on the live tile for the Pictures hub were based on those on the device; however, I'm still occasionally seeing photos that I have removed from the phone (using the delete option, as opposed to deleting via Zune).

Is there anyway to stop images from being used on the live tile, especially for those that have been removed from the pictures hub?

Comment: Do you have any copies in the "Saved Pictures" album?

Answer (score 5):

You can choose to show only pictures that you've marked as "Favorites". So if you put a picture in "Favorites", it will show up on the Pictures live tile.

Comment: This would presumably be a work around for ensuring it doesn't happen again yes.

Comment: Where is the setting to do this.  I would like to do the exact opposite of the OP, and have it use the camera roll.

Comment: Actually I cant find it in Windows Phone 8 right now.

Answer (score 2):

1. Open Photos by tapping on Photos live tile
2. Tap "..." and tap "Settings"
3. Tap "Shuffle Now"

It'll just renew the images cached for the Photos` live tile.
If you still see the same images, restart your phone for it to take effect.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

That is weird. Have you tried unpinning the pictures hub, and putting it back again? Maybe it caches the images and those are stuck for some reason.

Also, do you have any pictures marked favorite? I believe that it will show your favorite pics over the camera roll. I point this out because it is a way to control what goes there.

Comment: I don't have any pictures flagged as favourite, and I've seen this behaviour on both an HTC Titan, and a Nokia Lumia 800. I have also noticed that the backgrounds within the picture hub occasionally use a deleted picture also.

Answer (score 0):

Go to Settings -> storage sense -> phone -> temporary files and delete those. Afterwards you might need to restart your phone, but this should remove deleted Images from your tile.

Answer (score 0):

You can stop all images being used by live tile, but can't stop particular image.

To stop all images in live tile and get transparent tile. Do following

1.Open photos and select settings.

2.Select "single photo" in Start Tile Shows.

3.Don't choose any photo from "choose photo" button. Just go back and pin tile. You will not see any photos. You will get transparent tile.