# How to delete photos from OneDrive?

Tags: onedrive, pictures, lumia-520

I am Nokia Lumia 520 user. My phone showing some pictures. I want to delete but don't getting any delete button as others pictures. Pictures have text like from OneDrive.

How do I the pictures I have on my OneDrive?

Comment: Possibly related: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/839/106

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**How to remove a picture at OneDrive**

1. [Download the OneDrive app](http://www.windowsphone.com/s?appid=ad543082-80ec-45bb-aa02-ffe7f4182ba8)
2. Sign in to the OneDrive app using the same credentials as you use on your phone
3. Find the picture in the OneDrive app and delete it

**Observe**

The image will probably end up in the Trash at your OneDrive so you will have to remove it from there to if you really want it gone.

Comment: i am login in onedrive with my account but not geeting any pics but my phone showing pics :-(

Comment: Than I guess your pictures are not at the OneDrive? Can you post a screenshot of a picture of your? Have you tried deleting the picture by opening the Pictures app?

Answer (score -1):

Hello friends download one drive app if U have in Ur mob no need to download 
Open the App and select photos delete Ur unwanted pics and it will automatically deleted from one drive collection