# Photos deleted from my phone and one drive are still showing as title on the One Drive phone

Tags: onedrive, photos

My phone was set to back up photos to one drive. I have deleted the photos that I dont want from my phone, and also deleted them from One Drive, but the deleted photos are still showing as the Tile photos on the One Drive on my phone. Any ideas how to delete / use different photos for the One Drive tiles ? Phone is a Lumina 635.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/q/839/106

Answer (score 1):

Go to Settings -> storage sense -> phone -> temporary files and delete those. Afterwards you might need to restart your phone, but this should remove deleted Images from your tile.

Additionally you can select photos for your tile by adding them to your favorites.

Answer (score 1):

Since when `OneDrive` have live tiles on Windows Phone?
If you're referring to `Photos` live tile, Head here: https://windowsphone.stackexchange.com/a/8580/5566

Answer (score 0):

Go to **Settings > Photos+Camera** and you'll find an option called **Shuffle now** under the Live Tile section. This purges existing cached images for the live tile and refreshes them with latest all images / favourite images (based on your preferences).